# If I have a process with only one thread running on a multi core why is it moved from one core to another

Tags: process, multicore

Why is a process having only one core always migrated from one core to another. Assume the process is very simple and has a simple thread that is running. I observed that the OS always moves it from one core to another when executing. Why is this done? Isn't there overhead with continously moving the process? Why doesn't it execute on one core and keep execting on the same core forever?

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to this question, but the most obvious one is: heat.

Comment: is there a name for this behaviour of migrating the process?

Comment: @Ryan: I don't know, but the wikipedia-page on [Processor Affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) might help. If you are running linux [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-processor-affinity-certain-task-or-process.html) could help you change the affinity.